# Regex to prevent a particular character from occuring before a digit

Tags: java, regex

I want to have a regular expression in Java to match a pattern where `$` does not come before the first occurrence any digit in a given string. So far what I've got is `([^$].*?)(\\d+?)`, but it matches the strings where `$` comes a few characters before the first digit. Am I missing something?
For eg.,

`dfn$jnjkdd84fjbd$bjk` should be invalid (`$` comes before `8`), while

`vsdivnsoi5$ier5girneg` is valid (`5` and then `$`).

**EDIT**: Minimum one digit should be present in the string.

Comment: Could you show some valid strings and some not valid?

Comment: is `asda12asda$` valid?

Comment: I think without using the regex you can do it using logic.

Comment: @ashokramcse I intend to do it with regex since I'm learning it.

Comment: @nisargshah95 Can the `String` be `abc`, and is it valid ?

Comment: @Florent Bayle No. A digit is to be present. My apologies for not stating it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend helped me find a really short regex -

`^[^$0-9]+[0-9].*`

Answer (score 1):

`^[^$\\d]*[\\d].*$` should do the trick.

We check that all the characters before the first digit are not "$" and not a number.

```
final String invalid = "dfn$jnjkdd84fjbd$bjk";
final String valid = "vsdivnsoi5$ier5girneg";

final String regexp = "^[^$\\d]*[\\d].*$";

System.out.println(invalid.matches(regexp)); // false
System.out.println(valid.matches(regexp)); // true
```

Comment: That won't make a string `abc` valid.

Comment: @anubhava According to the edit just made to the post, the `String` must have at least one digit, so my answer is correct, as "abc" is not a valid `String`.

Comment: +1 Yes in that case this regex is correct just make it `"^[^$\\d]*\\d.*$"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `substring()` and `matches()` like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "adsaa12s$21";
    s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("$")); // upto $
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(s.matches(".*?\\d.*?")); // does my string contain digits?

}
```

O/P:

```
adsaa12s
true

s = "sfs$21";
O/P:
sfs
false
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
^[^\\$]*\\d+[^\\$]*\\$
```

Comment: Testing for "vsdivnsoi5$ier5girneg" at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html gave a negative result.

Answer (score 0):

```
  (?![^0-9]+\$.*)(?=.*?\d.*?\$.*)(^.*$)
```

use this.This uses a lookahead to ensure a digit before $.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yX3eB5/8

Comment: It gives a match when you use "dfn$jsdnjkdd8934fjbd$bjkdfbk" as input string.

Comment: It doesn't match `abc` even though that is valid input.